# UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput not correct size in IOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, ios8

In IOS 7 the method I'm using has plenty of room for both the login and the password input, however when jumping to IOS 8, the textfields seems to have grown leaving the textfield in the UIAlertView Cut off. Here is a picture of what ***Should be*** happening, and below that is what is happening in IOS 8.

[image: IOS 7]

[image]

So how do i return them to normal size so it all fits in the alert view?

here is my code

```
 UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                       initWithTitle:@"Add Job"
                       message:@"Set a job name and wage below"
                       delegate:self
                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                       otherButtonTitles:@"Add", nil];

    [av setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];

    // Alert style customization
    [[av textFieldAtIndex:1] setSecureTextEntry:NO];
    [[av textFieldAtIndex:0] setPlaceholder:@"Job Name"];
    [[av textFieldAtIndex:1] setPlaceholder:@"Wage"];
    [[av textFieldAtIndex:1] setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad];
    [av show];
```

Comment: File a bug report with Apple. Include a test app that demonstrates the issue. Also consider that `UIAlertView` is deprecated in iOS 8. If appropriate you should use its replacement.

Answer (score 0):

The issue no longer exists using Xcode 6 beta 2

Comment: hello...i am facing same problem but dont know how to update my xcode currently i am using Version 6.1 (6A1030)...can you plz help me how can solve this...

Comment: Let me check my code out later and try to find a solution